# How to increase Windows 10 clipboard history?

Tags: windows-10, copy-paste, clipboard

Windows 10 has this new feature that can be enable and then save last "copy".
After, when clicking on <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, I can view the history of my last copies.

Is there a way to increase this copy history list?
The default list shows only the last 25 copies.

This is the history clipboard:

https://www.howtogeek.com/351978/using-windows-10s-new-clipboard-history-and-cloud-sync/

Comment: What do you mean by `increase`? The clipboard history had all previous clipboard content item since logon. I don't think there is a hard limit.

Comment: it snows only the latest 20 copies..

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4464215 "Your clipboard history is limited to 25 copied entries. Older items—unless they're pinned—are removed automatically to make room for new clipboard items." You may need to use a 3rd party tool for more than 25 items.

Comment: @YuvalLevy - 20? 25? this is valuable information and should be part of the question

Comment: I have exactly the issue I want to increase clipboard history size to 50 or 60 items currently it provides only 27 or ~30 items which is not too much.

Answer (score 21):

The new Windows clipboard is still too new to be hackable.
It has also not externalized its functional parameters in the registry as of yet.

All that is known about it is that it is enabled via:

- *Settings > System > Clipboard*
- Group Policy (gpedit.msc) in
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > OS Policies >
  Allow Clipboard History*
- In the registry at
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows`
  by the values `AllowClipboardHistory` and `AllowCrossDeviceClipboard`.

That just about sums up everything that is known. We don't know any way of extending
its size beyond 25, as specified in Microsoft's article
[Get help with clipboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4464215/windows-10-get-help-with-clipboard),
and there is also no way to move or extend its window from the bottom-right of
the screen.

For more functionality, one is today still obliged to use third-party products,
of which there are many.

You may find some lists with reviews in the articles:

- [10 best Clipboard managers for Windows 10](https://windowsreport.com/clipboard-managers-windows-10/) (updated 2019)
- [Best Free Clipboard Replacement Utility](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-clipboard-replacement-utility.htm) (updated 2016)

These lists are missing my favorite of the open-source
[ClipAngel](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clip-angel/).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can actually increase your clipboard history so your best bet is to use a third party program like a [cloud based archive](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/archive-monitor-windows-clipboard-content-with-archiveclipboard).
You can find other clipboard programs [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/best-free-clipboard-manager-software-windows-10).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the above answers but as an alternative I am already using FARR ([Find and Run Robot](http://www.donationcoder.com/software/mouser/popular-apps/farr)) with KlipKeeper for clipboard history of around 100 clips. Extremely easy to use and fast, alot of customization options and many more plugins available. FARR and KilpKeeper are both available for free.
KlipKeeper can also paste the string as well as copy to clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

As been said, there currently isn't a way to increase the 25 item limit.
However, I'd like to suggest a free 3rd party alternative: **[CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/releases/)**.
It's free, open-source and doesn't phone home.

Answer (score 1):

Size of clipboard is specified within `ClipboardServer` variable (maybe), being `256000` by default (probably 256 kB) in:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ClipboardServer.MaxSizeAllowedInKBytes
```

Comment: on my Windows 10 Pro the value of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ClipboardServer.MaxSizeAllowedInKBytes` is 0x00001400 (decimal 5120), Im sure I didn't changed it by hands before

Answer (score -4):

In short:
Set Virtual memory of Windows to custom size, restart and it and increase the History capacity entries.

---

How to proceed in detail:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- sysdm.cpl [OK]
- |Advanced|
- Performace [Settings...]
- |Advanced|
- Virtual memory [Change...]
- C: (or drive where Windows is installed)

Custom size: (my PC has 8GB real RAM, so I set)

- Initial: 2048
- Maximum: 8196
  (Other drives (it there are) must be "No paging file" or "Custom size" also, not "System managed size".)

[OK] ...
It will request restart of PC.
Enjoy more cliboard capacity entries of <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>  ;)

Comment: This is not related to the question, we are talking about the clipboard, not the virtual memory

Comment: This answer is out of scope the virtual memory doesn't relate with the clipboard history in any way, delete this answer instead you get a - rating.

Comment: I have 96GB RAM and still only have 25 entries 